# Kähler manifolds are formal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, complex-geometry

I want to understand why Kähler manifolds are formal.
This was first proved by [Deligne, Griffiths, Morgan, Sullivan](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9e41/89a15d50cb1ccb92920d2fe55ae462f2de7c.pdf.)

---

> Let $\mathcal M$ be a minimal differential 
>   algebra and $H^*(\mathcal M)$ the cohomology 
>   of $\mathcal M$, viewed as a 
>   differential algebra with $d =0$.
>
> **Definition.**
>
> 1. $\mathcal M$  is  *formal*  if  there  is  a  map  of  differential  algebras  $\psi: \mathcal M \to  H^*(\mathcal M)$  inducing  the  identity 
>      on  cohomology.
> 2. The  homotopy  type  of  a  differential 
>      algebra  $\mathcal A$  is  a  *formal  consequence  of  its  cohomology*  if  its minimal  model  is  formal.
> 3. The  real  (or  complex)  homotopy
>      type  of  a  manifold  $M$  is  a  formal  consequence  of  the 
>      cohomology  $M$  if  the  de  Rham  homotopy  type  of  the  real  (or 
>      complex)  forms 
>      $\mathcal E$  is  a  formal  consequence  of  its  cohomology.

---

In section 6, the following (main) theorem is proved:

> Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold for which the 
>   $dd^c$-lemma holds (e.g. $M$ Kähler, or $M$ a Moisezon space). 
>   Then the real homotopy type of $M$ is a formal consequence of 
>   the cohomology ring $H^*(M; \mathbb R)$

Let $\{\mathcal E^*_M,d\}$ be the de-Rham complex on $M$, $\{\mathcal E^c_M,d\}$ the subcomplex of $d^c$-closed forms and $\{H_{d^c},d\}$ the quotient complex $\mathcal E_M^c/d^c \mathcal E_M$.

Using the $dd^c$-lemma ($\partial \bar\partial$-lemma), it is an easy calculation, that the natural maps 
$$\{\mathcal E^*_M,d\} \stackrel i\leftarrow \{\mathcal E^c_M,d\} \stackrel p\to \{H_{d^c},d\} $$
are quasi-isomorphisms and that the differential on $H_{d^c}(M)$ vanishes.

---

In the proof, the theorem follows immediately from the above. I don't see how and I am a little confused that there were no reasons given why the theorem follows. Only "This proves the claim and consequently [part (1)] of the theorem".

The maps seem to be maps of differential algebras, so this is fine.
But as far as I see, the theorem only follows if we can replace $\{H_{d^c},d=0\}$ with $\{H_M,d=0\}$.

---

Update/ Solution:
I repeat: The theorem only follows if we can replace $\{H_{d^c},d=0\}$ with $\{H_M,d=0\}$.
But the above argument shows, that the cohomologies are isomorphic. More precisely, the isomorphism is induced by $i$ and $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dg-algebra with vanishing differential is its own cohomology. The morphisms $i_*,\rho_*$ are isomorphisms between the cohomology of $(\mathscr{E}^*_M,d)$ -- which is $H^*(M)$ -- and the cohomology of $(H_{d^c}, d = 0)$ -- which is $H_{d^c}$, because the differential vanishes.

More generally if a dg-algebra $A$ is quasi-isomorphic to any dg-algebra $B$ with vanishing differential, then $B$ is isomorphic to the cohomology of $A$, pretty much by definition; hence $A$ is formal.

Comment: Thank you. I already had everything in mind what you said, for some reason I just failed to make the last (surprisingly easy) step. It's clear now.